# Fix Java warning on Jenkins startup with default Debian package install

Tags: ubuntu, debian, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins on a Debian system using the instructions here:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

It works fine, but gives a warning in the log on every startup:

"Java is not in the PATH nor configured with the javaPath setting, Jenkins will try to guess where is Java,this guess will be remove in the future"

What's the correct way to fix this warning?

I'm assuming adding something to /etc/default/jenkins, but I'm not 100% sure exactly what.

(tagging Ubuntu too, as the issue/fix should be the same there, as the Jenkins packages are common)

Comment: The is a message from inside `/etc/default/jenkins`. It's a shell script. You can examine it and see. It expects a env JAVA_HOME, or goes searching /usr/bin/java, /etc/alternatives/java, etc. You can edit and set a propoerty there or  in a jenkins.conf and.load it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or add java path to `PATH` variable.
Assuming you have *openjdk-8* installed you need to issue the commands:

to create `JAVA_HOME` variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

and to add it to `PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```